# How to remove ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1% in the URL

Tags: asp.net

I have created ASP.NET 4 project in visual studio 2012 with Master page.
Onclick of a button it appends data in the url.

This the Button control on the aspx page

```
<asp:Button runat="server" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" ID="btnSave" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click1"/>
```

and on the .cs page I have

```
   protected void btnSave_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        SaveInfo();
   }
```

When the button is clicked the info the text box are appended in the URL rather than calling the function `SaveInfo();`

```
Page.aspx?ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txtTitle=&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1
```

How do i disable the this and have the function invoked?

Comment: Can you show some relevant code?

Comment: I have corrected the question with and put relevant codes.

Comment: It is a bit strange the the link you are redirected is `Page.asp` and not `Page.aspx` for example. Are you having any JavaScript errors? Also check your HTML, there could be something that breaks it such as a tag not closing properly.

Comment: That is a typo error...am concerned on why it redirected info to the url rather calling the function

Comment: Are you having any JavaScript errors? Also check your HTML, there could be something that breaks it such as a tag not closing properly.

Comment: I have disabled all JS scripts but it still won't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109394/discussion-between-angwenyi-and-tasos-k).